# Getting Unknown error in eclipse. Runs perfectly in cmd

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, cmd

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ScientificCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    JPanel[] row = new JPanel[8];
    JPanel[] row2 = new JPanel[3];
    JButton[] button = new JButton[27];
    String[] buttonString = {   "7", "8", "9", "+", "√",
                                "4", "5", "6", "-", "³√",
                                "1", "2", "3", "*", "ⁿ√",
                                "0", ".", "/", "±",
                                "=", "sin", "cos", "tan",
                                "Clear", "x²", "x³", "xⁿ"};

    int[] dimW = {300, 54, 100, 109};
    int[] dimH = {35, 48, 100};
        Dimension displayDimension = new Dimension(dimW[0], dimH[0]);
        Dimension regularDimension = new Dimension(dimW[1], dimH[1]);
        Dimension rColumnDimension = new Dimension(dimW[2], dimH[1]);
        Dimension zeroButDimension = new Dimension(dimW[3], dimH[1]);
    boolean[] function = new boolean[4];
    double[] temporary = {0, 0};
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea (1,20);
    Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 14);


    ScientificCalc()
    {
        super("Scientific Calculator");
        setDesign();
        setSize(500, 400);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(7,5);
        setLayout(grid);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            function[i] = false;
        }

        FlowLayout f1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
        FlowLayout f2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,1,1);

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {   
            row[i] = new JPanel();
        }

        row[0].setLayout(f1);

        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {   
            row[i].setLayout(f2);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) 
        {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setText(buttonString[i]);
            button[i].setFont(font);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }

        display.setFont(font);
        display.setEditable(false);


        display.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        display.setPreferredSize(displayDimension);

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {   
            button[i].setPreferredSize(regularDimension);
        }

        for(int i = 15; i < 27; i++)
        {   
            button[i].setPreferredSize(regularDimension);
        }

        button[15].setPreferredSize(zeroButDimension);
        button[19].setPreferredSize(zeroButDimension);
        button[23].setPreferredSize(zeroButDimension);


        row[0].add(display);
        add(row[0]);


        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {   
            row[1].add(button[i]);
            add(row[1]);
        }

        for(int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
        {
            row[2].add(button[i]);
            add(row[2]);
        }

        for(int i = 10; i < 15; i++)
        { 
            row[3].add(button[i]);
            add(row[3]);
        }

        row[4].add(button[15]);

        for(int i = 15; i < 19 ; i++)
        {
            row[4].add(button[i]);
            add(row[4]);
        }

        row[5].add(button[19]);
        for(int i = 20; i < 24 ; i++)
        {
            row[5].add(button[i]);
            add(row[5]);
        }


        row[6].add(button[23]);
        for(int i = 24; i < 27; i++)
        {
            row[6].add(button[i]);
            add(row[6]);    
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }


    public void clear()
    {

        try 
        {
            display.setText("");
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                function[i] = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                temporary[i] = 0;
        } catch(NullPointerException e) 
        {  
        }
    }


    public void getSqrt() 
    {
        try {
            double value = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }


    public void getCbrt() 
    {
        try {
            double value = Math.cbrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }


    public void getNthRoot()
    {
        try {
            double result = 0;
            temporary[1] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            result = Math.pow(temporary[0], (1/temporary[1]));
            display.setText(Double.toString(result));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }


    public void getPosNeg() 
    {
        try {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            if(value != 0) {
                value = value * (-1);
                display.setText(Double.toString(value));
            }
            else {
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }


    public void getSqr()
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()), 2);
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }

    }



    public void getCube()
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()), 3);
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }

    }



    public void getNthPow()
    {
        try
        {
            double result = 0;
            temporary[1] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            result = Math.pow(temporary[0], temporary[1]);
            display.setText(Double.toString(result));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {

            }
    }


    public void getSin()
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }
    }


    public void getCos()
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }
    }


    public void getTan()
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Math.sin(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Double.toString(value));
        }   catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
            }
    }



    public void getResult() {
        double result = 0;
        temporary[1] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        String temp0 = Double.toString(temporary[0]);
        String temp1 = Double.toString(temporary[1]);
        try {
            if(temp0.contains("-")) {
                String[] temp00 = temp0.split("-", 2);
                temporary[0] = (Double.parseDouble(temp00[1]) * -1);
            }
            if(temp1.contains("-")) {
                String[] temp11 = temp1.split("-", 2);
                temporary[1] = (Double.parseDouble(temp11[1]) * -1);
            }
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        try {
            if(function[2] == true)
                result = temporary[0] * temporary[1];
            else if(function[3] == true)
                result = temporary[0] / temporary[1];
            else if(function[0] == true)
                result = temporary[0] + temporary[1];
            else if(function[1] == true)
                result = temporary[0] - temporary[1];
            display.setText(Double.toString(result));
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                function[i] = false;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == button[0])
            display.append("7");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[1])
            display.append("8");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[2])
            display.append("9");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[3]) 
        {
            //add function[0]
            temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            function[0] = true;
            display.setText("");
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == button[4])
            getSqrt();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[5])
            display.append("4");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[6])
            display.append("5");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[7])
            display.append("6");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[8]) 
        {
            //subtract function[1]
            temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            function[1] = true;
            display.setText("");
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == button[9])
            getCbrt();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[10])
            display.append("1");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[11])
            display.append("2");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[12])
            display.append("3");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[13]) 
        {
            //multiply function[2]
            temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            function[2] = true;
            display.setText("");
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == button[14])
        {
            temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            display.setText("");
            getNthRoot();
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == button[15])
            display.append("0");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[16])
            display.append(".");
        if(ae.getSource() == button[17]) 
        {
            //divide function[3]
            temporary[0] = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
            function[3] = true;
            display.setText("");
        }

        if(ae.getSource() == button[18])
            getPosNeg();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[19])
            getResult();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[20])
            getSin();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[21])
            getCos();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[22])
            getTan();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[23])
            clear();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[24])
            getSqr();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[25])
            getCube();
        if(ae.getSource() == button[26])
            getNthPow();
    }


    public final void setDesign() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch(Exception e) {   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ScientificCalc();
    }

}
```

Well, I wrote this code in Eclipse and when i click run it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at ScientificCalc.main(ScientificCalc.java:413)
```

So, I copy pasted this into notepad++ and saved it elsewhere.
Then, I tried it in CMD and the code works without a hitch. Help Please?

Comment: Please don't make us guess or scroll and search, what's line 413?

Comment: Btw, normally eclipse should display the problem in the editor (red marker) and tell you what the problem is.

Comment: _"Unresolved compilation problem"_ means there was a compile error in your code (i.e. a syntax error) that you did not fix.  Also, your heavy use of empty `catch` blocks is really bad.  Any exceptions thrown by your code will just silently disappear, and you'll get unexplainable weird behavior.  Don't do it.

Comment: 413 is the main(String args[]) line

Comment: it shows this warning on class declaration line:
    The serializable class ScientificCalc does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Comment: and this on the line where @override is written:
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Comment: ok.. removing the @override line did it. Thanks for your help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `@Orverride` should fix the problem because `@Override` indicates that you have used the same method somewhere else in your program and you want to 'override' it, which you don't in this case, you want to create it, not override it. To learn more about how to use the `@Override` method [Visit this link.](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/method-overriding-vs-overloading/)

Comment: Thank You kind sir.. I'll be sure to read up on it

Answer (score 0):

Removing The "@Override" does the job